# Handle correctly root URL using Angular and ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'd like my Angular website to get several routes using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), which are:

- `/` which renders `landing.html`
- `/howto` which renders `howto.html`

I tried the following, with no success:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('landing', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/landing.html',
            controller: 'LandingCtrl',
            data : { pageTitle: 'Landing' }
        })
        .state('howto', {
            url: '/howto',
            templateUrl: 'views/howto.html',
            controller: 'HowToCtrl',
            data : { pageTitle: 'HowTo' }
        });
```

I can access landing.html on `localhost/` but cannot access `/howto`, I get the message `Cannot GET /howto`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: are you using `#/howto` in url?

Comment: I'm using Html5Mode but it works find when I try to access `#/howto`, it redirects me to `/howto` and it works. But I cannot access `/howto` directly.

Comment: definitely sounds like server config problem. Don't have to configure server when not using html5Mode but when remove `#` you do